# Definition width and height on image_tag

Tags: css, image

where I have images with lazy loading, I don't have image_url sizes definition. You can see the critical section of The page block image as shown here:

```js
<img loading=lazy loading="lazy" class="lazy photoswipe__image js-photoswipe__zoom"
    data-index="{{ image_index }}"
    data-photoswipe-src="{{ block.settings.image_1.src | img_url: '1600x1600' }}"
    data-photoswipe-width="{{ block.settings.image_1.width }}"
    data-photoswipe-height="{{ block.settings.image_1.height }}"
    data-src="{{ img_url }}"
    data-widths="[180, 360, 540, 720, 900, 1080, 1500]"
    data-aspectratio="{{ block.settings.image_1.aspect_ratio }}"
    data-sizes="auto"
    alt="{{ block.settings.image_1.alt }}">
```

Can you please advise?

I don't understand where has to be input it